# Not able to create table space in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to create a table space in postgres in my mac.

I am getting below error, I tried giving `chmod 777` to the folder, still I am getting same error.

> ERROR: could not set permissions on directory
>   "/Users/abraham/database": Operation not permitted SQL state: 42501

---

> ERROR: could not set permissions on directory
>   "/Users/abraham/database": Operation not permitted SQL state: 42501

Comment: You need to give the user PostgreSQL runs as *ownership* of the directory using the `chown` command

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the postgresql server cannot set permissions on the given folder.

To set permissions on a folder you need to have write permissions on the *parent folder*.

The database normally runs under the postgres user which presumably does not have write access to /Users/abraham.

On addition as per Craig's comment postgres needs to own the actual tablespace directory.